# Domino Designer : Xpages - The project was not built since the source file could not be read

Tags: xpages, domino-designer-eclipse

I tried to create a new java class using the 'New Java Class' menu option. The class is named ATMUtils.java. After I entered the details for the class, I did not get the Editor showing the new class. But when I went into Package Explorer, that class was listed under the 'Code/Java' section.

Under the Problems view, I see the error ***'The project was not built since the source file .....ATMUtils.java  could not be read'***.

Even after doing a 'Project - Clean' and restarting Designer multiple times, the error does not go away.

When I do a right click and select 'Delete', I get the error:
***'An unexpected error occurred while performing the refactoring. Reason: Resource is not local'***.

When a colleague of mine looked at that same db in his client, he did **not** see this class under Package Explorer view ( the db is on a development server - not local).

How do I remove this class from the project ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove database from workspace in Designer so that it is not visible in Designer/Applications anymore. Close Notes Client and Designer. Reopen Notes Client and open database in Designer.

Comment: @Knut:  I am just starting off with Java and have read this same issue in different places as well as myself.  Do you know the reason behind these errors?  Something developers are doing wrong?